My Iterator does not break during iteration
I have written a simple iterator that I'd like to break from when a specific condition is met. However, it does not do so when the condition is met. Below is the iterator and skeleton classes to show how it is implemented and called by searchByDate function. The issue is that is does not break even though it goes into the loop and the value 15 is always printed, which is the limit for the Order searches. It should break when it find the current Order, but it doesn't even though the order is found
        import { plusDays} from "./dateUtils.ts";

        import {
            isEmpty,
        } from "./collection-utils";

        export class DateIterator {
            date: Date

            limit = 15
            currentCount = 0
            constructor(date:Date) {
                this.date = date
            }


            next() {
                if (this.currentCount <= this.limit) {
                    const search = plusDays(this.date.toDateString(),1)
                    console.warn({currentNumberOfDays: this.currentCount}, 'Number of days iterated')
                    this.currentCount++
                    return { done: false, value: search}
                }
                else
                {
                    return {
                        done: true,
                        value: this.date
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        export class DateIncrementor {
            initDate: Date
            constructor(initialDate:Date) {
                this.initDate = initialDate
            }

            [Symbol.iterator]() {
                return new DateIterator(this.initDate);
            }
        }
        
        class Order {
            //...
            
            orderItems = ()
        }
        
        class OrderService {
            getOrdersForDate = async(date:string) =>{
                return new Order()
            }

            isCurrentOrder = (orderDetails:Order) =>{
                return true
            }
        }

        const searchByDate = async(date:Date) => {
            const orderService = new OrderService()
            const  nextDaySearchIterator =  new DateIncrementor(date)
            let count = 0
            let result = {} as Order
            for await (let currentDate of new DateIncrementor(date) ){
                count+=1
                if(date){
                    const orderDetails:Order = await orderService.getOrdersForDate(currentDate)
                    if(orderService.isCurrentOrder(orderDetails)) {
                        if(!isEmpty(orderDetails.orderItems)){
                            result = orderDetails
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log('Number of executions of iterator',count)
            return result? result : null
        }


Please [edit] to provide a [mre] that we can use to demonstrate the issue for ourselves, without reference to private/undeclared types or values, and without pseudocode. When we copy and paste the code into our own IDEs, we should see the problem you're seeing without having unrelated problems.

Have you added a console.log in front of the break to confirm that we evaluate to true to even enter the condition?
Would love to see some console.logs as there's some missing logic for me to replicate the code on my local machine

Yes, I did. It simply refuses to break out of the for loop. The service classes themselves are pretty involved but I'll try to provide a minimally reproducible example

Apparently it didn't work out to provide a minimal reproducible example?

Solved this a while ago

This still isn't a [mre], and the fact that you solved it might help you but is unlikely to help future readers unless you edit the question and answer to provide the relevant information.

I solved the problem by using an AsyncIterator and using it in for await loop
